# It is possible to add a permanent sub-menu in the down part of my app??? (like html frame style menu)

Tags: android, menu

i am making an android APP, and i need to have a submenu, permanent, same menu in all my windows. This menu haves the navegability between the parts of my app, (googlemap view, invite, config and tabhost with listviews)

i can do a menu that only changes the superior part of the window? i mean, like html frames

how i can do it?

thanks

Comment: Sounds unnecessary. Frames in html were terrible and this sounds worse.

Comment: ok, but then i have to reuse the same code in all the windows...